# Can I close a file input dialog using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to close a file input dialog using javascript?

Here is my use case:

I have a drag&drop or click `div` that feed an hidden file input. If the user click on it, the file input dialog opens. If the user drag a file from the file input dialog and drop it in my `div`, the file is well received by my `drop` event but Chrome crashes because the dialog is still opened.

Bottom-line: I want to close the file input dialog if a file is dropped in my `div` dropzone while the dialog is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block accepting drop events when the user clicks on the div. Add a `isDialogOpen` boolean to your code and if it's true, return false on the drop events. If your browser still crashes, then try to report it, because it sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Ya but issue would be to reset `isDialogOpen` variable when the dialog is closed. You could bind onchange event but this event is not fired in all cases, for example closing the dialog clicking cancel button. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Yes, that's not so nice. It would worth a test, to see if the `body` receives mousemove events while the dialog is open. If not, then that can cancel the `isDialogOpen` variable.

Answer (score -1):

The focus event can be caught to reset the `isDialogOpen` variable. It works well in Safari, Chrome(MAC), but not in Firefox.